# New attribute creation using ogr and regex

Tags: sql, ogr, ogr2ogr, fields-attributes, regular-expression

I've got a folder full of dxf files with elevation values included as part of a long text attribute. I've written a regex expression to extract the elevation value, and would like to add it as a new attribute to an output Mapinfo file.

I'd prefer to complete this using command line and ogr if possible, as it's already doing most of the work to convert the files. Python alternatively. QGIS as a last resort.

Could this be completed using a SQL query in the `ogr2ogr` command?

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK OGR SQL doesn't support **regular expressions** natively, but...

> By default, the REGEXP operator has no implementation in SQLite. With
>   OGR >= 1.10 built against the PCRE library, the REGEXP operator is
>   available in SQL statements run by OGR.

Source: http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_sqlite.html

However, see also:

- http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/4823
- http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/changeset/24963

Alternatively, you can use the `LIKE` operator and the `SUBSTR` function in your [OGR SQL](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/ogr_sql.html) statements.